# Python app uses old filed on EC2 instance

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an interesting problem:

There is an EC2 instance, on which py3env is stored

I deploy my web app from pyCharm to EC2 and run the server (runserver 0.0.0.0)

Since last week the web app uses OLD files, which I have already deleted from EC2. I check app files on EC2 - they are correct, but still I have 'old' app running.

Maybe there is some EC2 cache problem or what?

Answer (score 1):

There is [nice documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) about your question.